# How to read serial data first and then set it to update tkinter label?

Tags: python

I am trying to write a python code to read serial data and then extract temperature sensor data from it. After that, I have to update a label in GUI with this temperature value.
When I comment the GUI section, I am able to read the serial data on terminal, but when I include GUI section, my code does not respond. Please help me.

```
import serial
import tkinter
from tkinter import *

class SerialViewer:
    def __init__(self):
        self.win = Tk()
        self.ser = serial.Serial(
            port = "COM3",
            baudrate=9600,
            bytesize=8,
            timeout=2,
            stopbits=serial.STOPBITS_ONE)

    

    def makewindow (self):
        self.win.title("6205BA")
        self.win.geometry("600x300")

        self.tmp = StringVar()
                
        Temperature = Label(self.win, text = "Temperature")
        Temperature.grid(row = 0, column = 0, sticky = E, padx =0, pady = 2)

        TmpVal = Label(self.win, textvariable = self.tmp)
        TmpVal.grid(row = 0, column = 1, sticky = E, padx =0, pady = 2)

    def update(self):
        serialString = ""
        while(1):
            if(self.ser.in_waiting > 0):
                serialString = self.ser.readline()
                data = serialString.decode("utf-8")
                check = data.startswith('A')
                if(check):
                    result = data.split(',') # splitting by ,
                    tempdata = float(str(result[1])) # taking temp data
                    #print("\n The temperature is : ",tempdata,"Deg Celcius")
                    self.tmp.set(tempdata) # taking temp data
       
        self.ser.close()
        self.win.after(2000,self.update)        

    def run(self):
        self.makewindow()
        self.update()
        self.win.mainloop()

SerialViewer().run()
```

Comment: You have an infinite loop inside `update()`; once you enter that function, no other part of your program ever executes.  You're on the right track with `.after()`, you just need to make a *single* attempt at reading the serial port per call to the function, then exit the function so that the GUI mainloop can do its work.

Comment: @vizsatiz, thank you very much. it was helpful.